# how to put HTML form tag

Tags: html

I have HTML tag in my JSP page like this:

```
<form action="updateaddr" method="post">
    <p>
        <label>
            电话：
            <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" value="${person.phoneNumber}"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            密码：
            <input type="password" name="password"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="注册"/>
</form>
```

Then below the form tag, I am trying to put button that would redirect to another page.

```
<a href="personal?id=${id}">
    <button>返回</button>
</a>
```

I want to place this button next to

```
<input type="submit" value="注册"/>
```

Currently it is placed below this when running Tomcat.

I appreicate if someone could help me.

Comment: Show your CSS, please. There's probably no reason you couldn't put the link inside the `form`, allowing inline-block styling to do what you're asking for.

Comment: Inside an `a` element, an `button` element is invalid. You need to describe the problem in terms of desired functionality, not in terms of invalid markup. To link to another page, just use a link, with no `button` element. (You can style the link to look like a button if you prefer, though this may be misleading.)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/w9SGz

Just put the link inside the form.

```
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="注册" /> 

    <a href="personal?id=${id}">
       <button>返回</button>
    </a>
</form
```

UPDATE: You'd need to give the button a type to prevent oddness: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/w9SGz/2

Jukka is correct that this could be considered invalid markup, and I know for a fact that some browsers don't like it. I agree that styling a link as a button is a better approach. However, that wasn't the question.

---

If you don't want to do that, negative margins may help, though it's a bit finicky and fragile:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/w9SGz/1

```
#myButton {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: -26px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: It does not redirect to the page I want. It redirects to updateaddr with Nullpointer exception which is not what I want.

Comment: Agreed, but the question was about CSS and layout, not markup. Downvoting is inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript and place it within the form element:

```
<input type="submit" value="注册"/>
<button onclick="window.location.href='personal?id=${id}'">返回</button>    
</form>
```

This works fairly consistently across browsers that have JavaScript enabled

Comment: I downvoted before I recalled that anchors around buttons are a bad idea, but this is a perfectly good answer. I can't retract unless you edit your answer. If you do, please comment here to notify me.